# Create Cookie Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to find a way to **count Clicks** on a specific Button filtered by the User's IP Address so only 1 click is registered (Per Day for example).

Right now i'm not trying to find a Completely stable Solution for this, just to filter out the clicks so a User can't click 5 times and populate the counter with 5 clicks.

So i thought why don't set a cookie `(cookie[:installed] = true)` so i can do something like this:

```
  def click_button
    url_to_redirect
    unless cookies[:installed]
      click_counter.increment
    end
  end
```

(I don't know if that is a good Solution for this, just brainstorming. If someone has a better Idea, you're more then welcome to Explain it to me.)

Besides that, i didn't had any luck implementing this "Cookie Solution" although i read through the [Rails API on Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

How can i implement this and where do i Start ? (I read that creating the Logic in the Model is Bad).

Forgive my Newbieness, Cheers

**Problem Progress:**

**1.)** In my Controller's Show Action i set the Cookie =>

```
  def show
    cookies[:installed] = false
  end
```

Comment: can you post the view code where the link is showing and the controller code.

Comment: It's a simple Link (link_to "Download", '#') and it's located in the SHOW view. The controller action is Empty because i'm trying to FIND how to achieve this :)

Comment: if count reaches to 5 then the link should not be clicked?

Comment: No, when a user clicks the link for the first time = Update Count. If he clicks it again = Don't Update Count.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather store this info in the session, rather than in the cookie. So for example like this.

```
def download
  unless session[:clicked] do
    session[:clicked] = true
    do_something #remember to change this
  end 
end
```

You could also store that info in the database to make sure the user can't bypass your check by launching some other browser or cleaning up the cookies. For example create a `Downloader` model with an `:ip` field and search the downloaders by `request.remote_ip` before serving the file.

And if we are talking about file download remember to use `send_file` instead of redirecting.